# How to group array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i need all items with the same id [id_promo] or [name] to be grouped and if possible all names to be ordered by alfabetic order

my array is :

```
   Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [nome] => 0012 – Inês Marinho Lopes [id_promo] => 1897 [foto] => 1898 [entrega] => 12/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 18/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
[1] => Array ( [nome] => 0015 – Daniela Palhares [id_promo] => 1912 [foto] => 1913 [entrega] => 30/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 29/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
[2] => Array ( [nome] => 0031 – Cláudia Fonseca [id_promo] => 2026 [foto] => 2027 [entrega] => [devoluçao] => [devolvido] => Não ) 
[3] => Array ( [nome] => 0015 – Daniela Palhares [id_promo] => 1912 [foto] => 1913 [entrega] => 30/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 29/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
)
```

and i need them to be grouped like this :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [nome] => 0031 – Cláudia Fonseca [id_promo] => 2026 [foto] => 2027 [entrega] => [devoluçao] => [devolvido] => Não  ) 
[1] => Array ( [nome] => 0015 – Daniela Palhares [id_promo] => 1912 [foto] => 1913 [entrega] => 30/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 29/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
[2] => Array ( [nome] => 0015 – Daniela Palhares [id_promo] => 1912 [foto] => 1913 [entrega] => 30/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 29/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
[3] => Array ( [nome] => 0012 – Inês Marinho Lopes [id_promo] => 1897 [foto] => 1898 [entrega] => 12/03/2016 [devoluçao] => 18/03/2016 [devolvido] => Não ) 
)
```

i tried a few foreach combinations but i cant make it work...

tks

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, you don't need to change the structure of the array, just sort it into the right order. If so, see [this reference answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/157957).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method uasort combined with a callback function

```
$arr = Array(); //This is your base array
function compare($a, $b) {
    if ($a['nome'] == $b['nome']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['nome'] < $b['nome']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($arr, 'compare');
```

This will sort your array only on the [nome] Key. I think you should try to enhanced this to work with [id_promo] and/or [name].

You can find a detailed documentation on [usort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach($oldArray as $key => $item)
{
   $newArray[$item['id_promo']][$key] = $item;
}

ksort($newArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Reference for [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: tks for the help..but not im getting :Array ( [2026] => Array ( [6] => Array ( [nome] => 0031 – Cláudia Fonseca =>.. and not [0] => Array ( [nome] => 0031 – Cláudia Fonseca